# How to compile a cpp to a dll in visual studio 2010 express

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I have a cpp which depends on couple of headers in the same folder. I need to compile this cpp to a dll. How do I do it in visual studio 2010 expresS?

I found few articles on web for visual studio 2008 but I could not use it in 2010. Any pointers would be highly appreciated. Btw, I am a java programmer. CPP is all new to me, I am compiling some one else's cpp to dll.

Thanks,
Abi

Comment: the procedure in VS2010 is pretty much exactly the same as in VS2008

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx

Comment: @Xeo..I am not sure whats wrong asking a question that way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer, and select `Properties...`. Under `Configuration Properties -> General` there's an option called `Configuration Type`. If you change it to `Dynamic Library (.dll)`, your project will generate a DLL when it is built.

Answer (score 1):

As a start point, you can use "Create New Project from Existing Code" as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/754c3hy7.aspx) - specify that you want a DLL project when prompted.

Once you have a project in place that encapsulates your CPP code file, you can find other info on specific project settings in MSDN, or post new questions as you need to.