# Mod java application in using C++

Tags: java, c++, oop, reflection, java-native-interface

### The context

I am writing an application in Java which is moddable. The application searches a `/mods` directory for `.jar` files and uses `org.reflections` to find `@Mod` annotations on classes. It then creates a `newInstance()` of the class, and injects the mod's objects into the application's registries. The objects that are being injected into the application registries are primarily `java.util.Supplier<T>`s, where `T` is a complex object, such as a [Tile](https://github.com/Volts-of-Doom/voltsofdoom/blob/master/voltsofdoom/src/main/java/vision/voltsofdoom/coresystem/play/tile/Tile.java).

That all works fine when writing the mod in Java.

- **If I wanted to make a mod for my application in C++ (as an example), how could I go about that?**

### Some approaches

- 1. Through comments we have determined that translation code would not work
- 2. Perhaps a different approach would be to *not* convert have either the modder, or the application convert the C++ code to Java, but to use a take on the JNI to load the C++ code as a library? Java can call methods from `.dll`s using the `native` keyword, assuming that it knows the name of the method it will call, and the library is loaded. If C++ can be compiled into a `.dll`, then would that help?
     [How to compile a cpp to a dll in visual studio 2010 express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288895/how-to-compile-a-cpp-to-a-dll-in-visual-studio-2010-express)
- 3. Although I don't know a lot about it, perhaps a tool like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) would work for making the files cross compatible?

Would any of these three be viable solutions?

Any additional information or clarification, please ask.

Comment: 1. Yes, JNI (or perhaps JNA) would work. 2. Converting code does not look to me like a viable solution. Using libraries (such as JNI or JNA) that allow use of compiled modules would be better. 3. This question is *very* broad and might not be a great fit for this site.

Comment: Hmm I agree that it is broad. I'll look into those suggestions. I think I'll also rephrase the question to cut the ambiguity. Thanks!

Comment: A big part of what makes this question too broad for Stack Overflow is, in my opinion, the fact that you've left open what languages you're looking for a solution in. If you would [edit] the question to focus *specifically* on C++, then that would go a long way to making this something that can be concretely answered here.

Comment: @CodyGray that is a good start - I'll edit that